# Run multiple script in a container

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to add multiple scripts in my docker file and run it when the container is up. startup.sh is an application and only when it's up and running we can run playbook.sh. This is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  rstudio_package_manager:
    privileged: true
    image: 'rspm_gh:sid'
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 34242:4242
      - 32121:2121
    environment:
      - RSPM_LICENSE=My license
    volumes:
      - ./playbook.sh/:/tmp/playbook.sh
      - ./startup.sh/:/usr/local/bin/startup.sh
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM rstudio/rstudio-package-manager:latest

# Expose necessary ports
EXPOSE 4242/tcp
EXPOSE 2112/tcp

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/startup.sh"]

# Specify the entry point and startup command
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--"]
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/startup.sh","/tmp/playbook.sh"]
```

startup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x

# Deactivate license when it exists
deactivate() {
    echo "Deactivating license ..."
    /opt/rstudio-pm/bin/license-manager deactivate >/dev/null 2>&1
}
trap deactivate EXIT

# Activate License
if ! [ -z "$RSPM_LICENSE" ]; then
    /opt/rstudio-pm/bin/license-manager activate $RSPM_LICENSE
elif ! [ -z "$RSPM_LICENSE_SERVER" ]; then
    /opt/rstudio-pm/bin/license-manager license-server $RSPM_LICENSE_SERVER
elif test -f "/etc/rstudio-pm/license.lic"; then
    /opt/rstudio-pm/bin/license-manager activate-file /etc/rstudio-pm/license.lic
fi

# lest this be inherited by child processes
unset RSPM_LICENSE
unset RSPM_LICENSE_SERVER

# Start RStudio Package Manager
/opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rstudio-pm --config /tmp/temp/rstudio-pm.gcfg
```

This is my playbook.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
alias rspm='/opt/rstudio-pm/bin/rspm'
rspm create repo --name=prod-cran --description='Access CRAN packages'
rspm subscribe --repo=prod-cran --source=cran
rspm sync --wait
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can ony have one entry point in a dockerfile. Ideally you should run both scripts in separate containers

Comment: Can you direct on how to do that?

Comment: Split the current service into two separate services.

Comment: I think you can concate the two sh files and currently entrypoint command into one file, which starts with `tini --` after that the content fof startup.sh and finally the content of playbook.sh

Comment: Can you rewrite the code as an answer here, so that itll be easy for checking. @AdamP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple entry point in a docker image.However, you can use alternative to launch multiple process.

For example, you can use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to administrate your process

Install supervisor in your container

`RUN apt-get install -y supervisor`

Copy the supervisor configuration file from host to your container

`COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf`

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:playbook]
command=/bin/sh -c "/tmp/playbook.sh"

[program:startup]
command=/bin/sh -c "/usr/local/bin/startup.sh"
```

In your Dockerfile use this command to launch supervisor

`CMD ["supervisord"]`